# Adding Launch Screen Removes Autosizing

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard, screen, launch

Since Apple is requiring a storyboard launch screen in a few months I went ahead and tried to add one. Adding one is simple and it works just fine but it screws up the layout after loading the app. No longer does a larger screen automatically adjust the resolution, instead I'm left with an SE layout on an 8 Plus screen placed in the top-left corner with the background image repeating (like wallpaper from a 90s website). I'm not using constraints, but I'm not even sure if that's the issue. If so I have a feeling I have a lot of work ahead of me (keep in mind I've never had a need for constraints). A side thought though is, from what I understand, Apple wants all apps to look correctly on all devices... makes perfect sense. But my apps have always appeared correctly no matter the device. So it's ironic that adding the launch screen is breaking my apps' appearances. Is it the constraints? Is there an alternative solution? Or is there hopefully something simple in the launch screen that needs to be changed? Thank you!

Comment: If you weren't using a launch storyboard and didn't have all sizes in your launch image you would have had black bars top and bottom and not been using the entire screen. With a launch storyboard you get the full screen size and this is when not using constraints is going to bite you since you have probably made assumptions on the size of the screen

Comment: Thanks for the info I really appreciate it. Sounds like the answer is what I feared but just to confirm, only adding constraints will fix the issue? Because it sounds like using launch images will not suffice come Jun 30th.

Comment: You can do it without constraints, but you end up with a lot of special-case code and it may break again if Apple releases a device with a different resolution.  Autolayout and constraints have been the recommended approach for many years.

Comment: Until the recent iphones I never had any reason to add constraints as my apps looked perfect on any device. They are simple tools with simple GUIs. I couldn't see anyone complaining about the black bars, except now obviously Apple is. I appreciate the help a bunch. I have 90 days at least for a surplus of tedious/not fun work.